# Deleted post with AJAX still showing on other users page until refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I’m working on the forum page of my website and trying to include functionality for editing and deleting a post by a logged in user who originated the post, like so:

```
function getPosts(){
        $.getJSON("fetch_post.php", function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i, user){
                if (user.parent_id == 0){//if its a post
                    if ($('.media-wrapper .media[data-id = '+user.id+']').length == 0){//if post does not exist on the page before
                        var userName  = $(".gist_params input.uname").val();
                        if (userName == user.name){//if logged in user is the originator of this post
                            var post= //an html showing the post, and then a delete and edit button
                            }else{//if its another user's post
                                var post= //an html showing only the post, without delete and edit button                   
                            }
                        $(".media-wrapper").prepend(post);
                    }
                 }else{//if its a reply to a post
                   $.each(data, function(i, user){
                     if ($('.reply_media .reply_media_body[data-id = '+user.id+']').length == 0){
                       var par_id = user.parent_id;
                       var parent_cont = $('.media-wrapper .media[data-id = '+par_id+']');
                       var reply = //an html showing the reply to the post
                       parent_cont.find('.media-body .reply_media').prepend(reply);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
    getPosts(); 
    setInterval(getPosts, 5000);
```

Here is my code for deleting a post:

```
$(document).on("click", ".media .comm_del", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the post?")){
            var post_id = $(this).attr('del-id');
            var post_to_del = $('.media-wrapper').find('.media[data-id = '+post_id+']');
            $.post("del_post.php", {"post_id": post_id}, function(data){
                if (data = "yes"){
                    post_to_del.remove();
                    getPosts();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

NB: please note that posting works fine and all users pages are automatically updated. The issue is with when a post is deleted, only the user who deletes sees update on his/her feed while other users still see the deleted post until their page is refreshed. What I want is for all the users pages to be updated automatically at the `setInterval` expiration.

Answer (score 1):

So you're adding new posts if they haven't been seen before, but nothing *removes* old posts that are no longer in the list.

Before updating, get a list of all current post IDs on the page. As you go through the list, note the IDs that you see. When you're done, delete any that *weren't* seen.

```js
function getPosts() {
  var existing = {};

  $('.media-wrapper .media[data-id]').each(
    function () {
      var did = this.getAttribute('data-id');

      existing[did] = false; 
    }
  );

  $.getJSON("fetch_post.php", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, user) {
      existing[user.id] = true;

      if (user.parent_id == 0) { //if its a post
        if ($('.media-wrapper .media[data-id = ' + user.id + ']').length == 0) { //if post does not exist on the page before
          var userName = $(".gist_params input.uname").val();
          if (userName == user.name) { //if logged in user is the originator of this post
            var post = //an html showing the post, and then a delete and edit button
          } else { //if its another user's post
            var post = //an html showing only the post, without delete and edit button                   
          }
          $(".media-wrapper").prepend(post);
        }
      } 
      else { //if its a reply to a post
        $.each(data, function(i, user) {
          if ($('.reply_media .reply_media_body[data-id = ' + user.id + ']').length == 0) {
            var par_id = user.parent_id;
            var parent_cont = $('.media-wrapper .media[data-id = ' + par_id + ']');
            var reply = //an html showing the reply to the post
              parent_cont.find('.media-body .reply_media').prepend(reply);
          }
        });
      }

      for ( var did in existing )
      {
        if (! existing[did])
        {  
          $('.media-wrapper .media[data-id=' + did + ']').remove();
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```